# My script src in HTML is not calling and activating my javascript file successfully

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!-- Custom JavaScript file -->
<scrpit src="./js/main.js"></scrpit>
```

If I press control+click on this src name, i go successfully to javascript file that i want to activate (which should mean that I have wrote the file's name and place well enough), but when i open the html page the functions in the script do not work.
To check if the problem is within the js code, i went and copied the js code inside the the html file, which worked properly.
But why wouldnt it work when i put it in a separate js file and call the file in the manner above?

Comment: `<scrpit>` is not `<script>`.

Comment: believe me sir, I have wasted 7 hours today on this... Thanks alot..

Comment: Try to configure your Coding Environment. So that you don't have to waste time on such things.

Comment: yes sir, i will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your code. 
Your code:

```
<scrpit src="./js/main.js"></scrpit>
```

Try to use this:

```
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Errors of this kind can just be closed as a typo, it doesn't need an answer, it's not that useful to anyone else reading in future. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (item 2)